# Shade Smooth creates gradient artifact that shows through materials

Tags: mesh, materials

I've noticed that if I take a simple cylinder and choose **Object Context Menu > Shade Smooth**, it creates a gradient artifact that's obvious even when a material is applied to the cylinder. Is it possible to shade smooth without this artifact? Thanks.

[image: Shade smooth artifact]

Comment: it creates these artefacts because it tries to smooth between the perpendicular faces, try the Auto Smooth option (Properties panel > Object Data > Normals)

Comment: Oh yeah, the combination of Shade Smooth + Auto Smooth = a much better result. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates these artefacts because it tries to smooth between the perpendicular faces, try the *Auto Smooth* option in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Normals*.